# Set Custom Date for Posts

Tags: date

I have a blog im working on in draft form. These blog posts are relevant to various days in the past few weeks but I would like to keep them hidden for the moment. When I publish one it gets todays date, is there a way to choose what date it has?

Comment: Please try that question at the wp dot org forums. It's off topic for thís site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can put custom date by editing the `published on` date on the top right of the post/page edit.

See the image attached for better understanding.

[image]